# How to handle JSON exception objective c

Tags: objective-c, json

Before I make url, which I will use to fetch json, user has to input some data first.
If the input data is wrong, the JSON will not be fetched properly.

But I cannot figure out how to handle that exception of calling JSON with wrong url.

this is my code:

```
NSError *error;
NSMutableDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                             JSONObjectWithData:url
                             options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                             error:&error];
if (error){
    NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
}

else{

    @try {
        if (json){
            [Constants shared].salt = json[@"salt"];
```

The last line of code is where the exception occurs, since the user had put the wrong input.
SO obviously, there wont be a proper json response fetchet, and there will be no "salt" object.
Error I get is:

```
-[__NSArrayM objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x146aa310
```

I tried putting json fetching in @try @catch, but it didn't work out.

Any suggestions ?

EDIT:

this is the json responce I get, when the user types in the right code:

```
{
user_id: "22066",
salt: "ce8c0f9e3e1add06bebc1acded7b692b68efddb87bfdc5bb1fb516f6a3e24425"
}
```

This is what i get, when the code is invalid:

```
[ ] (empty array)
```

Comment: Check if the returned object is actually a dictionary. In your case, it seems to be an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: Also check for `json == nil` and not `error != nil`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't that the dictionary lacks an object for the key `@"salt"`, it's that `json` isn't a dictionary in the first place. Take a close look at the error message and you'll see that it's an array. The problem isn't the key, but the fact that arrays don't respond to `-objectForKeyedSubscript:`.

Accordingly, when you get an object back from `-JSONObjectWithData:...`, check that it's not `nil` and that it is in fact a dictionary before you try to access its contents. You can check it like this:

```
if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    // put the code that accesses `json` here
}
```

That condition will be `false` if `json` is `nil` or something other than a dictionary. You could add an `else` clause to take any necessary steps to recover if you're relying on getting the data.

Comment: Yeah, this works.
WHen the user enters the right data, I get the JSON object.
WHen It doesn't however, I get an empty Json array returned.